# One-hot encoding for duplicate words

Tags: natural-language, categorical-encoding

I'm currently studying NLP and was practicing one-hot encoding for sentences at the word level.

My question is, if we have multiple examples of the same word in a sentence, does one-hot encoding normally assign separate "slots" for each instance of the same word?

For example, if we have the sentence "The cat sat on the mat." we can observe that the word "the" is used twice. Is each "the" assigned a separate entry, such that the encoding would look like:

```
1  0  0  0  0  0
0  1  0  0  0  0
0  0  1  0  0  0
0  0  0  1  0  0
0  0  0  0  1  0
0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: Note that assigning different encodings to different instances of the same word would prevent the model from learning anything useful!

Comment: @tddevlin That's a very good point, I hadn't thought about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you consider the capitalization of the first

> The

It might look like your example.

But if not.  It would look like:

```
1  0  0  0  0  0
0  1  0  0  0  0
0  0  1  0  0  0
0  0  0  1  0  0
1  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  1
```

One hot encoding assigns a **unique** code for each **unique** word.